# Two or more articles in the same entry on bibtex

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I would like to cite two papers that treats the same problem in the same entry of a reference using bibtex. It is very common in my field to put many reviews about some topic in one only entry of the bibliography. Here comes an exemple, with two articles:

[image]

It is really easy to do if you put all the references in the same tex file of the paper text, but using bibtex I never found any option to do this! Any suggestion? Obs.: I commonly use the class revtex4-1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE !

The package `mcite` allows you to write

```
\cite{ref1,ref2*}
```

to combine these two references into a single entry. RevTeX also has implemented similar markup and can be used the same way. Read Author’s Guide to [AIP Substyles for REVTEX 4.1](https://cdn.journals.aps.org/files/revtex/aipguide4-1.pdf)

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein and Second Author",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905"
}
@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Like this. \cite{dirac,*einstein}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, it is simpler then I thought! Thank you very much!

Comment: @DyanaDuarte If the answer was useful, you can mark it as accepted.