# Multiple entries in the same reference

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to quote several articles from my `.bib` file in the *same* reference (bibliography entry)

For example

> [1]
>   N. Bahcall, J. P. Ostriker, S. Perlmutter, and P. J. Steinhardt, Science 284, 1481 (1999);
>   A. G. Riess et al., Astron. J. 116, 1009 (1998);
>   S. Perlmutter et al., Astrophys. J. 517, 565 (1999); 
>   C. L. Bennett et al., Astrophys. J. Suppl. Ser. 148, 1 (2003).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not correspond to any of the accepted norms of bibliography.  Have you seen any journal or book cite in that way ?  Rather you may have multiple citations in the text like [1] [2] [3] [4] and refer them as : 

[1] N. Bahcall, J. P. Ostriker, S. Perlmutter, and P. J. Steinhardt, Science 284, 1481 (1999).
[2] A. G. Riess et al., Astron. J. 116, 1009 (1998) 
[3] S. Perlmutter et al., Astrophys. J. 517, 565 (1999) 
[4] C. L. Bennett et al., Astrophys. J. Suppl. Ser. 148, 1 (2003).

Comment: @ParthaD. Some reference styles allow for 'combined' citations. I think in chemistry this is not that uncommon.

Comment: Well, sorry then... it's something that I learnt after a quarter century in research.  Thanks @moewe :)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15747/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239106/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209585/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460357/35864

Comment: @ParthaD. Some citation/bibliography customs are highly field-dependent. In mathematics its is rare to see combined citations like this, but in some physics journals and chemistry they are more common.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `@Set` entry with biblatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@set{A,
  entryset    = {A:V1,A:V2,A:V3,A:V4},
}
@article{A:V1,
       author = {Riess, Adam G. and Filippenko, Alexei V. and Challis, Peter and Clocchiatti, Alejandro and Diercks, Alan and Garnavich, Peter M. and Gilliland, Ron L. and Hogan, Craig J. and Jha, Saurabh and Kirshner, Robert P. and Leibundgut, B. and Phillips, M. M. and Reiss, David and Schmidt, Brian P. and Schommer, Robert A. and Smith, R. Chris and Spyromilio, J. and Stubbs, Christopher and Suntzeff, Nicholas B. and Tonry, John},
        title = {Observational Evidence from Supernovae for an Accelerating Universe and a Cosmological Constant},
      journal = {Astron. J.},
         year = 1998,
        month = Sep,
       volume = {116},
        pages = {1009-1038},
          doi = {10.1086/300499},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {astro-ph/9805201},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph},
}
@article{A:V2,
       author = {Bahcall, N. A. and Ostriker, J. P. and Perlmutter, S. and Steinhardt, P. J.},
        title = {The Cosmic Triangle: {Revealing} the State of the Universe},
      journal = {Science},
         year = 1999,
        month = May,
       volume = {284},
        pages = {1481},
          doi = {10.1126/science.284.5419.1481},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {astro-ph/9906463},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph},
}
@article{A:V3,
       author = {Perlmutter, S. and Aldering, G. and Goldhaber, G. and Knop, R. A. and Nugent, P. and Castro, P. G. and Deustua, S. and Fabbro, S. and Goobar, A. and Groom, D. E. and Hook, I. M. and Kim, A. G. and Kim, M. Y. and Lee, J. C. and Nunes, N. J. and Pain, R. and Pennypacker, C. R. and Quimby, R. and Lidman, C. and Ellis, R. S. and Irwin, M. and McMahon, R. G. and Ruiz-Lapuente, P. and Walton, N. and Schaefer, B. and Boyle, B. J. and Filippenko, A. V. and Matheson, T. and Fruchter, A. S. and Panagia, N. and Newberg, H. J. M. and Couch, W. J. and {The Supernova Cosmology Project}},
        title = {Measurements of {\ensuremath{\Omega}} and {\ensuremath{\Lambda}} from 42 High-Redshift Supernovae},
      journal = {Astrophys. J.},
         year = 1999,
        month = Jun,
       volume = {517},
        pages = {565-586},
          doi = {10.1086/307221},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {astro-ph/9812133},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph},
}
@article{A:V4,
       author = {Bennett, C. L. and Halpern, M. and Hinshaw, G. and Jarosik, N. and Kogut, A. and Limon, M. and Meyer, S. S. and Page, L. and Spergel, D. N. and Tucker, G. S. and Wollack, E. and Wright, E. L. and Barnes, C. and Greason, M. R. and Hill, R. S. and Komatsu, E. and Nolta, M. R. and Odegard, N. and Peiris, H. V. and Verde, L. and Weiland, J. L.},
        title = {First-Year {Wilkinson} {Microwave} {Anisotropy} {Probe} ({WMAP}) Observations: {Preliminary} Maps and Basic Results},
      journal = {Astrophys. J. Suppl. Ser.},
         year = 2003,
        month = Sep,
       volume = {148},
        pages = {1-27},
          doi = {10.1086/377253},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {astro-ph/0302207},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
subentry,
style=numeric-comp,
doi=false,
maxbibnames=8,
minbibnames=1,
alldates=year,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\hspace*{-0.3em}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=title, null]
    }
  }
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{A}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

*(the above bib entries are generated automatically and should be checked for [common errors and other mistakes before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/software-generated-bibliographic-entries-common-errors-and-other-mistakes-to-ch) in real documents)*

Comment: Even if the bib entries are returned that way from the astronomy site, they're wrong and braces around the surnames should be removed; also `"{...}"` for titles is dubious, because it doesn't give the bib style any choice about capitalization.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your comment. I added a warning to the post

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for your edit! Out of curiosity: Does the capitalization of `@article` influence biblatex?

Comment: @samcarter No, the capitalisation of the entry types and field names in `.bib` files plays absolutely no role for Biber or BibTeX. I just prefer all lowercase names. On the TeX side capitalisation matters, though, since TeX is case sensitive try `\DeclareFieldFormat{Pages}{#1}` and see how it does not work compared to `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}`.